# How to exclude a list of files and folders while using tar?

Tags: bash, tar

I have a pathname of files and directories listed in a FILE named MyExclude.list.

Is it possible to exclude the list of files from being added to the tar archive?

Comment: do ```man tar``` and search for ```exclude``` - there's a whole family of exclude-s

Comment: `tar -czf backup.tar.gz -X /path/to/exclude.txt /path/to/backup` is what I needed